# Is there any way I can have a barrier within Device code that is controlled by Host?

Tags: cuda, barrier

For example, my code is something like this (but it doesn't work and the kernel stalls):

```
__device__ __managed__ int x;

__global__ void kernel() {

    // do something 

    while(x == 1); // a barrier 

    // do the rest 
}

int main() {
    x = 1;
    kernel<<< 1, 1 >>>();
    x = 0;

    //...
}
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: I'm very curious what your application is. I'd like to know when this would be advantageous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with the current implementation of managed memory because managed memory requires *exclusive* access to managed data by the device, when kernels are running.  Host access to managed data during the time when kernels are running will lead to [undefined behavior](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-coherency-hd), typically seg fault.

This should be possible using zero-copy techniques, however, including the `volatile` recommendation from @Cicada.

Here's a worked example:

```
$ cat t736.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

__global__ void mykernel(volatile int *idata, volatile int *odata){

  *odata = *idata;
  while (*idata == 1);
  *odata = *idata+5;
}

int main(){

  int *idata, *odata;

  cudaHostAlloc(&idata, sizeof(int), cudaHostAllocMapped);
  cudaHostAlloc(&odata, sizeof(int), cudaHostAllocMapped);

  *odata = 0;
  *idata = 1;  // set barrier
  mykernel<<<1,1>>>(idata, odata);
  sleep(1);
  printf("odata = %d\n", *odata); // expect this to be 1
  *idata = 0; // release barrier
  sleep(1);
  printf("odata = %d\n", *odata); // expect this to be 5
  cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // if kernel is hung, we will hang
  return 0;
}


$ nvcc -o t736 t736.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t736
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
odata = 1
odata = 5
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

The above assumes a linux 64 bit environment.